# Wiring a 4 pins slide switch

Tags: wiring

I want to know how can i wire this toggle switch to obtain 3 positions :

- Position 1 : Turn Off System
- Position 2 : Turn On System
- Position 3 : Write "High" On a microcontroller (ATtiny84)

This is the slide switch i am willing to use : [Link](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/New-Quadratic-Unclassified-Data_XKB-Enterprise-SS-13D07-L5-B_C480349.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know which pin of the switch is common pin, i think it might be pin no.1 or no.2

if pin no.2 was common, do this wiring :

[image]

if pin no.1 was common, do this one :

[image]

the diode is preventing Write HIGH on your ATtiny's digital input when you just want to turn it ON and not to do that in same time (Position 2)
if you tell me which pin is common pin, i'll give you the exact answer

Comment: Thanks @Hamid 'Smith' Salehi for the response. In both cases the ground of the battery is not connected ? Thanks again and i am sorry i can not up your comment cause i do not have enough reuptation.

Comment: all you have to do is : connect the negative pole (-) of your battery >>> to GND pin of ATtiny, that's it

Comment: Sounds good thanks, i will keep looking to see which pin is the comman cause i can not find out through the datasheet of the switch.

Comment: you can use buzzer mode on a multimeter, the pin which connects to all other pins in every switch Positions, is common pin

Comment: I do not have a multimeter unfortunately but if you can see the datasheet i believe they mentionned the common on the circuit on the right : https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2003101832_XKB-Connectivity-SS13D07L5B_C480349.pdf

Comment: I believe the common is pin 3.

Comment: i checked it, it seems the common pin is pin no.2, at first check the upper picture

Comment: So it's basically this pin : https://imgur.com/a/vOieFwp , which corresponds to pin 3 in your draw ?

Comment: i don't know why but i can't see the picture, you can easily find a common pin on a switch by using a battery and a lamp

Comment: The problem on my side is that the switch is already on a pcb and i do not know how they are wiring it, i tried the method with battery and led but it turns on in 2 different pins so it's confusing to me.

Comment: This is a direct link to the image : https://i.imgur.com/FWSFq1g.png

Comment: yeh, it's the common pin of the switch

Comment: Sounds good, Thanks for the hel^p

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use a DP3T switch. If you can stand the voltage drop of a Schottky diode, you can use @Hamid's scheme wired as so:
(pin 1 has the gap to the next pin)

The divider loads against leakage in D1 up to 70°C at least, for very high temperatures you might have to reduce the values. A divider is used to prevent applying more than Vdd to the input pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYbYth.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The lower schematic shows a circuit that does not suffer the leakage or voltage drop of the Schottky diode but has one extra component- eg. PEMH9,115 dual digital transistor (in dashed box). R8 prevents transient current through the MCU input while M1 turns on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, really appreciate the advices